# Differentiation and Binomial

Tags: derivatives, binomial-coefficients, implicit-differentiation

Q. If $$f(x) =\displaystyle \prod_{r=0}^{n} \left( \binom{n}{r} x + r+1 \right)$$ and $$f'(0)= \frac{3}{2} (7!)$$ then find the value of n.

**My Attempt**- I took $\ln$ both sides to get- $$\ln(f(x)) = \displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{n}\left(\ln\left(\binom{n}{r} \, x +r+1\right) \right)$$

Now, If we differentiate $\ln(f(x))$ and put $x=0$, we get - $$ \frac{f'(0)}{f(0)} = \frac{f'(0)}{(n+1)!}= \displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{n} (\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{r+1})$$

Now, I'm stuck and clueless from here on!

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you first need to take the log of everything the original product was multiplying not just the Choose(n,r)*x term.

Comment: Sorry about that, I already took log of everything but failed to mention in it! I will do corrections.

Comment: All good. Although I feel the RHS is going to look ugly number for any n. Try the hint from the answer provided!

Comment: Ok, I will try! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct,
$$f'(x)=f(x)\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{\binom{n}{r} x + r+1}\implies f'(0)=(n+1)!\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{r+1}.$$
Now consider
$$\int_0^1(x+1)^ndx=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\int_0^1x^rdx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, It helped me . Thanks a lot!

Comment: Infact, this is such a wonderful approach to this problem!